# node.js throttle particular function

Tags: node.js

I am facing a problem with node.js script, it goes out of memory and gets killed.

The pseudo code looks like this:

---

```
function a(){
   fetch data async from web // lets say it takes time - t
   b();
   c();
   a(); // called recursively
}
function b(){
  // some time consuming async task taking time lets say - t1

}
function c(){
  // some time consuming async task taking time lets say - t2
 }

a();
```

---

In above the time t1 + t2 is greater than time t, function a() is executed much rapidly than b and c, this consumes all the available limited memory (3GB), I want to limit function a() call, allow *some* function b() & c() call to complete. I don't want to serialise execution but want function a() not to consume all resources. So far only thing I have come up is using setTimeout(a(), 1000) but want to know if there are any other nice solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Why not waiting for `fetch`, `b` and `c` to finish before calling `a` again?

Comment: That will slow down overall execution, defeating the async design. function b() and c() are independent and function a() does not needs to wait for b() and c() to complete.

Comment: I think `async.during` can solve your problem, https://github.com/caolan/async#duringtest-fn-callback  do you need to set any parameter before calling `a` recursively such as requiring data result of `b` or `c`?

Comment: function a() does not needs any input from b() and c(). Will take a look at async. Thanks :)

Comment: Wait, function `a` is not a separate task, it really is just `b` and `c`. You're piling up the work there and as a result getting out of memory. I've never heard that waiting for tasks to be finished goes against async design...just use the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async), launch `b` and `c` in parallel if you want to save some time, and wait for them to finish.

Comment: function b() and function c() receive input from function a(), the time for b() and c() will depend on input, sometimes b() will be faster than c() and vice versa. Lets say b(1) is slower than b(2), but while b(1) completes b(2) will have to wait, I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Yes, still, you have to wait for both tasks to be done, and by that it's meant receiving a callback, not setting a timeout with your estimate of how much time is needed. Easiest and clearest way to do so? Use [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) (in your case, not `async.eachSeries` that would run the tasks sequentially and take more time).